# How to see coming resourse params in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have a query

```
$scope.product_detail = Source1.get({ 

FirmId: $routeParams.firmId, 
ProductId: id 

});
```

With this query come a resourse : 
Resource { $get=function(), $save=function(), $query=function(), more...}

How to see the properties of this resourse, for example  `$scope.product_detail.id`, coz console.log($scope.product_detail.id)  give me 'undefined' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This resource's `get` method is asynchronous.  Assuming your REST back-end returns `{id: 123}`, it will be available on `product_detail` as soon as your REST response is received.

If you try to access it immediately after you call `get`, you won't see your values because they haven't been received yet.

The `get` function can take a `success` and `error` callback:

```
Source1.get({}, function(response) {}, function(error){});
```

The value of `response` will be the same reference as `$scope.product_detail`, so the callbacks are unnecessary... unless you want to execute code specifically on return.

Comment: thanks, but how to check when it "readable"? mb there is .when()  function in angular?

Comment: See edit.  You can pass a `success` callback.  You only need this is you need to call some code upon receipt of the data.  If you are just binding, the callback is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to display it before it is available. You can make it display the data in the success callback.

```
$scope.product_detail = Source1.get({     
  FirmId: $routeParams.firmId, 
  ProductId: id },
  function(resource) {
    console.log(resource.product_detail.id);
});
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but this give me "Error: resource.product_detail is undefined" (

Comment: @user2560165 how you display it depends on how the resource is returned.